# Vue 3: How to Access Setup Variable in Component Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Consider the following simple example using the composition API in Vue 3. I'm trying to have an instance of `test` available in the functions of my component.

```
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Test',
  setup(){
    let test = ref()
    
    onMounted(() => {
      doSomething()
    })

    return{
      test,
      doSomething
    }
  }
})

function doSomething(){
  console.log(test) //<-- undefined
  console.log(this.test) //<-- undefined
}
</script>
```

How do I access `test` inside `doSomething()`? My understanding is that anything returned by `setup()` should be available throughout the component much like a `data()` attributes from the options API.

Comment: why don't you put the function inside the setup hook?

Comment: Primarily because it feels cleaner to separate it. The real function is rather large and it gets harder to read when it's inside `setup()`.

Comment: make pass the ref value as param

Comment: Passing it as a parameter works, but then it's not available to other functions that also need to reference it. Maybe I should just stick to the old Vue 2 way of doing it.

Comment: you could build some composable function and set the test outside that function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to pass the `ref` as a parameter

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Test',
  setup () {
    let test = ref(null)

    onMounted(() => {
      doSomething(test.value)
    })

    return {
      test,
      doSomething
    }
  }
})

function doSomething (param) {
  console.log(param); // null
}
</script>
```

---

#### another approach:

```
// functions.js
import { ref } from 'vue'
export let test = ref(null)
```

```
// vue-file
<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { test } from '../utils/functions.js'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Test',
  setup () {

    onMounted(() => {
      doSomething(test)
    })

    return {
      test,
      doSomething
    }
  }
})

function doSomething (param) {
  console.log(test.value); // <-- instant access
  console.log(param.value); // <-- import via parameter
}
</script>
```

Comment: `test.value` is `undefined` as well. I failed to mention that I tried that as well.

Comment: Even after giving it a type and setting the variable's value, it's still not defined inside `doSomething()`.

Comment: This works, but then `test` is only available within `doSomething()`. My ultimate goal is to have a `test` property available to other functions in my component as well.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I've added another approach. Keep in mind, it's all javascript, so you got many ways to solve your problem. Hope you get an idea.

Comment: This isn't just "another approach" but local vs global state