# use variable that defined in setup(), in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-script-setup

I define a function in vue setup(), i just wanna use the var thats defined in this function, in my template. I return the function name, but how can I return the variable?

```
    <script lang="ts">
    import ApiService from "@/core/services/ApiService";

    export default {
      name:"pricing",
      setup(){
        setInterval(()=>{
          getPrice()

        },3000)

        function getPrice(){
          ApiService.get('https://....').then(({ data }) => {
            var price = data[0]
            var date = new Date()
            var today = price.today;
            var last_update =  date.toLocaleDateString("fa") + " - "+ date.getHours()+":"+ date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds(


          })
          return{
            getPrice
          }
        }}
    </script>
```

```
`<template>
 <p class="bg-purple p-2 my-5 last-update">{{today}}</p>
    </template>
`
```

I want to show today variable in template.

Comment: [Vue 3: How to Access Setup Variable in Component Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68293543/14945696)